# How to search for zagat selected places only in Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

How do I search for Zagat selected places only in Google Places api, as when I follow the docs and add **zagatselected** to the query, the results fail and give invalid request.

Notice: I'm a billing user (i.e. I enabled billing in the API Console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Become a Enterprise Customer

Some features of the Places API — such as review summaries, and certain request filters — requires additional licensing, available as part of a Places API enterprise license.

You can verify that your account has been enabled for Places API enterprise features as follows:

Visit the APIs Console and log in with your Google Account.
Select the project that was created for you when you signed up.
The project name will start with Google Maps APIs for Business.
Click the Services link from the left-hand menu.
The Places API - Zagat Content service should be enabled. Note that only the initial owner of the project will be able to see the Places API - Zagat Content service.
The Places API service should be disabled.

from [Google Places API Document](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#m4b_authentication)

Comment: Yeah they actually phoned me 3-4 months ago and told me so.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain Zagat data you have to [become an enterprise user](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/); just being a "billing user" is not enough.

Per Google: "[The zagatselected parameter is experimental, and only available to Places API enterprise customers."](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

Comment: Yeah they actually phoned me 3-4 months ago and told me so.